# How can multiple struct fields be generics that use the same higher-kinded lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

My struct `ReadingState` takes the function `recv_dgram` as argument in its `new()` method. `recv_dgram` takes as an argument a buffer with some lifetime `'r`, and returns a `Future` of a certain type. The `Item` of this future contains the buffer that was fed as an argument, with the same lifetime `'r`.

This is how `ReadingState` looks like:

```
struct FragMsgReceiver<'a, A, FUNC: 'a>
where
    FUNC: for<'r> FnMut(&'r [u8])
        -> Future<Item = (&'r [u8], usize, A), Error = io::Error>,
{
    frag_state_machine: FragStateMachine,
    recv_dgram: &'a mut FUNC,
    get_cur_instant: &'a mut FnMut() -> Instant,
}

struct ReadingState<'a, 'c, A, FUNC: 'a, F>
where
    F: Future<Item = (&'c mut [u8], usize, A), Error = io::Error>,
    FUNC: for<'r> FnMut(&'r [u8])
        -> Future<Item = (&'r [u8], usize, A), Error = io::Error>,
{
    frag_msg_receiver: FragMsgReceiver<'a, A, FUNC>,
    temp_buff: Vec<u8>,
    res_buff: &'c mut [u8],
    opt_read_future: Option<F>,
}
```

The return type of `FUNC` is not the same as `F` because they use different lifetimes.

The structs by themselves can compile, but I can not use them correctly in the rest of my code. For example, this happens when I try to call `frag_msg_receiver.recv_dgram` and assign the result to the field `opt_read_future` of `ReadingState`:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> src/frag_msg_receiver.rs:80:30
   |
80 |               let mut fdgram = match mem::replace(&mut reading_state.opt_read_future, None) {
   |  ______________________________^
81 | |                 Some(read_future) => read_future,
82 | |                 None => (*reading_state.frag_msg_receiver.recv_dgram)(
83 | |                     &mut reading_state.temp_buff),
84 | |             };
   | |_____________^ expected type parameter, found trait frag_msg_receiver::futures::Future
   |
   = note: expected type `F`
              found type `frag_msg_receiver::futures::Future<Item=(&[u8], usize, A), Error=std::io::Error> + 'static`
```

A dream solution (this is not valid Rust code) will be something of the form:

```
struct ReadingState<'a, 'c, A, FUNC: 'a, F> 
    where for <'r> {
        F: Future<Item = (&'r mut [u8], usize, A), Error = io::Error>,
        FUNC: FnMut(&'r [u8]) -> F,
    }
{
    // ...
}
```

I don't know how to achieve this with the existing syntax.

Edit: I made the smallest possible self contained example I could, but it doesn't compile for possibly different reasons. I am including it here ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=949893b9b62025d2474d147d35b63475&version=stable)):

```
trait MockFutureTrait {
    type Item;
    fn get_item(self) -> Self::Item;
}

type FnTraitObject = FnMut(&mut [u8]) -> MockFutureTrait<Item=&mut [u8]>;

struct MockFuture<T> {
    item: T,
}

impl<T> MockFutureTrait for MockFuture<T> {
    type Item=T;
    fn get_item(self) -> Self::Item {
        self.item
    }
}

struct FragMsgReceiver<'a> {
    recv_dgram: &'a mut FnTraitObject,
}

struct RecvMsg<'a,'c,F>
    where F: MockFutureTrait<Item=&'c mut [u8]> {

    frag_msg_receiver: FragMsgReceiver<'a>,
    res_buff: &'c mut [u8],
    read_future: F,
}


fn main() {
    let mut recv_dgram = |buf: &mut [u8]| {
        MockFuture {
            item: buf,
        }
    };

    let fmr = FragMsgReceiver {
        recv_dgram: &mut recv_dgram,
    };
}
```

The compilation error I get:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <[closure@src/main.rs:33:26: 37:6] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'r mut [u8],)>>::Output == MockFutureTrait<Item=&'r mut [u8]> + 'static`
  --> src/main.rs:40:21
   |
40 |         recv_dgram: &mut recv_dgram,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `MockFuture`, found trait MockFutureTrait
   |
   = note: expected type `MockFuture<&mut [u8]>`
              found type `MockFutureTrait<Item=&mut [u8]> + 'static`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `for<'r> std::ops::FnMut(&'r mut [u8]) -> MockFutureTrait<Item=&'r mut [u8]> + 'static + 'static`

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `noncompiling_lifetime_trait`.
```

I'm not sure that I know what I'm doing, and why the compile problems changed. You might have an idea.

Comment: Are you saying you want the return value of `FUNC` to be the same as `F`? I'm not sure I can follow the question that is being asked unfortunately. Can you reduce this to a single example, preferebly something runnable in the [playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/)?

Comment: Side note: your `mem::replace` on the `Option` can be recreated by using [take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take)

Comment: @Timidger: I didn't know about `take`. This is really cool, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're hoping to do isn't possible as of Rust 1.20. You need [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/a7cd91048eea3d7ae83bec20446e62bad0c45381/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) in order to bind the correct lifetime on the type parameter `F`. The solution would look like this (obviously, I can't test it because generic associated types are not implemented yet):

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait FragFutureFamily<A> {
    type F<'a>: Future<Item = (&'a [u8], usize, A), Error = io::Error>;
}

struct FragMsgReceiver<'a, A, FUNC: 'a, FF>
where
    FF: FragFutureFamily<A>,
    FUNC: for<'r> FnMut(&'r [u8]) -> FF::F<'r>,
{
    frag_state_machine: FragStateMachine,
    recv_dgram: &'a mut FUNC,
    get_cur_instant: &'a mut FnMut() -> Instant,
    _phantom_future_family: PhantomData<FF>,
}

struct ReadingState<'a, 'c, A, FUNC: 'a, F, FF>
where
    F: Future<Item = (&'c mut [u8], usize, A), Error = io::Error>,
    FF: FragFutureFamily<A>,
    FUNC: for<'r> FnMut(&'r [u8]) -> FF::F<'r>,
{
    frag_msg_receiver: FragMsgReceiver<'a, A, FUNC, FF>,
    temp_buff: Vec<u8>,
    res_buff: &'c mut [u8],
    opt_read_future: Option<F>,
    _phantom_future_family: PhantomData<FF>,
}
```

Note: I left the `F` type parameter on `ReadingState` because the type is slightly different from `FragFutureFamily::F`, though if you can make the types agree, you could change the type of `opt_read_future` to `Option<FF::F<'c>>`.

---

As a workaround, you could use `Box<Future<...>>` instead of a type parameter for the `Future` type.

Comment: I didn't know about PhantomData. I assume that it is used to add constraints for types, very interesting. I hoped that I will not need to use the Box<> workaround, as I want to avoid the allocation ): I added self contained code example, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: You can't have a function return a `MockFutureTrait<Item=&mut [u8]>`, because that's an unsized type. You need to return a concrete type that implements `MockFutureTrait`, but you can't specify a single concrete type that works for *every* lifetime.

Comment: My attempts to use Boxed idea could be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253306/lifetime-problems-for-a-function-returning-a-boxed-trait-that-contains-a-referen)